# react popconfirm inside popconfirm

Tags: reactjs, antd

How can I show another Popconfirm inside another Popconfirm?

The function handleDelete it return true or false. I can see on console the log message but i cannot see the second popconfirm.

```
render: (text, record) =>
<Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => { 
    if(this.handleDelete(id)){
      console.log("it show true")
      return (
          <Popconfirm  title="Force Delete?" onConfirm={() => {
           this.handleInside()
          }}>
          </Popconfirm>
      )
   }
   }}>
  <Button type="link"><b>Delete</b></Button>
</Popconfirm>
}
```

Comment: Maybe the returned jsx in the function assigned to onConfirm isn't used anywhere. That might not be the correct place for having nested jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onConfirm` appears to be a event handler when you confirm the action on your `Popconfirm`, so it doesn't make sense to return JSX inside that method and assume that it will somehow magically render it on the screen.

What you can do is setting the state of the force delete status and render it based on that state.

Something like this:

```
const [forceDelete, setForceDelete] = useState(false);
...
<Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => { 
    if (this.handleDelete(id)){
      setForceDelete(true);
....

{forceDelete && <Popconfirm ... onConfirm={() => { ... setForceDelete(false); }} />}
...
```

Comment: Thanks now I think of it make sense for the return JSX